# How to close JNDI connection?

Tags: jdbc, jndi

I am using JNDI for database connection. I have created a XML file in META-INF for connection.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- The contents of this file will be loaded for each web application -->
<Context crossContext="true">

    <!-- Default set of monitored resources -->
    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>

    <Resource name="jdbc/myDB" auth="Container"
        type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="600000"
        username="root" 
        password="abc123" 
        driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/game"/>
</Context>
```

In java class I am using following code to get the connection

```java
    Context envContext;
    Datasource ds;
    envContext = new InitialContext();
    Context initContext  = (Context)envContext.lookup("java:/comp/env");
    DataSource ds = (DataSource)initContext.lookup("jdbc/myDB");
    Connection con=ds.getConnection();
```

But, how can i close the connection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `DataSource` will be in charge of the management of the physical connection to the database. When you call `con.close` (which is **a must**), the physical connection will be back to the pool and set the connection in a sleep state. In case a connection is closed, the `DataSource` will be in charge to obtain a new connection, if possible.

In short, you should not worry about closing the physical connection.

Comment: So should i not close the connection?

Comment: @TechGuy you should always call `Connection#close` after using the connection. Also, retrieve the connection in the narrowest possible scope.

Comment: @techguy: please use correct tags in next questions. Java is waaaay to generic and this is not jsf related at all